# The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

I keep getting the error `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.` when I try to run this code.

It seems that the line `myProcess.Start()` is the problem.
Can anyone help me out.

```
        string python = @"C:\Users\mk\Desktop\A.py";

        // python app to call 
        string myPythonApp = "sum.py";

        // dummy parameters to send Python script 
        int x = 2;
        int y = 5;

        // Create new process start info 
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

        // make sure we can read the output from stdout 
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        // start python app with 3 arguments  
        // 1st arguments is pointer to itself,  
        // 2nd and 3rd are actual arguments we want to send 
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + x + " " + y;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        // assign start information to the process 
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Python script with arguments {0} and {1}", x, y);

        // start the process 
        myProcess.Start();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to call `A.py` as an executable file, such as a `.exe`, which it is not (it's just text, not an assembly).

Instead, you can call Python through CMD to run `A.py`, and pass in `sum.py` as an extra argument.

Here's an example of that:

```
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"); 

// run python from console.
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "/C python A.py " + myPythonApp + " " + x + " " + y; 

Process myProcess = new Process(); 
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
// start the process 
myProcess.Start();
```