# How to open a textfile with the default editor in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, file, .net-core

In .NET Framework I can simply do `Process.Start(filename);` butin .NET Core I get this exception:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not
>   a valid application for this OS platform.'

How can I start `testfile.txt` with my default app?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Comment: @Barns while related, I think these are completely different questions

Comment: It is completely different. In your question it's about starting an executable while I want to open a non executeable file with the default app (without starting the defualt app directly)

Comment: This is because `UseShellExcute` by default is set to `true` in .NET Framework and `false` in .NET Core

Comment: well, how about these examples: [.Net Core 2.0 Process.Start throws...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl) OR [C# Execute Application Using Process.Sta...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153242/c-sharp-execute-application-using-process-start-as-params-to-cmd-and-active-re) Or even [The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638802/the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-application-for-this-os-platform)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open it like such:

```
new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename)
    {
        UseShellExecute = true
    }
}.Start();
```